# Returning array pointer produces "warning: return from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I was reading around C and I saw that you cannot return an array from a function but you can return a pointer, from this source: [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm).

The compiler gives this warning:

```
test.c:50: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
```

I wrote similar code to they gave but I'm receiving a

```
/*¯¯¯Input to Values¯¯¯*/
int * lineToXY(char line[]) {
    int i,j,k;
    double x,y;
    char xvalue[15];
    char yvalue[15];
    static double xypair[2];
    /*Split into two strings*/
    for (i=0;sizeof(line)>i;i++) {
        if (isValidChar(line[i])) {
            for (k=0;isValidChar(line[i+k]);k++) {
                xvalue[k] = line[i+k];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    for (i=i+k;sizeof(line)>i;i++) {
        if (isValidChar(line[i])) {
            for (k=0;isValidChar(line[i+k]);k++) {
                yvalue[k] = line[i+k];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    /*Parse each string as a double*/
    x = strtod(xvalue, NULL);
    y = strtod(yvalue, NULL);
    xypair[0] = x;
    xypair[1] = y;
    return xypair; /*<-------- this is the line which the compiler is referring to.*/
}
```

The code above is from this: http://pastebin.com/jU48qypV

Thanks in advance, and hope you all had a lovely Christmas.

Comment: What type is `xypair` and what type is `lineToXY()` returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the object you are returning doesn't match the return type of the function:

```
int * lineToXY(char line[]) { -----+   You've declared lineToXY to return a pointer to
  ...                              |   int, but you declare xypair as an array of
  static double xypair[2]; --------+   double; in the return statement, the expression
  ...                              |   xypair "decays" to an expression of type 
  return xypair; <-----------------+   double *, which is not int *, hence your warning
}
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array; this expression is not an lvalue (IOW, it cannot be the target of an assignment).

Assuming you change the return type of the function to `double *`, this code will work, but...

By declaring `xypair` `static`, you're creating a single instance that exists across all invocations of the function; this is often *not* a good idea.  The function is no longer *re-entrant*, which
may or may not matter for your purposes, but it's not a great habit to get into.

What might be better is to pass the destination array to the function, rather than trying to return it:

```
void lineToXY( char line[], size_t linesize, double xypair[] )
{
}
...
int main( void )
{
  char inputLine[SOME_SIZE];
  double pair[2];
  ...
  lineToXY( inputLine, sizeof inputList, pair );
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's cleared it up better than I could have ever hoped! :)

Answer (score 0):

In C

Function cannot return an array and you should be returning int *

You should have something like

```
int *p= malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

p[0] = 5;
p[1] = 10;

return p;
```

in your funtion `lineToXY()`

Else you can have a static array like shown and return the base address of the array.

```
static int r[2];

r[0] = 5;
r[1] = 10;

return r;
```

Your array is of type `double` and you are trying to return `int *` please fix that also either return `double *` or have `int` array

Answer (score -1):

You should generally not do that anyway. But the actual problem is the function returns `int *` and you should return `double *`, `int *` and `double *` are incompatible pointers.

You can do it in a few ways I can think of, and your `lineToXY` function does a lot of uneeded work, just try this first option

```
void lineToXY(char line[], double xypair[2])
{
    char *token;
    char *saveptr;
    char *endptr;


    token = strtok_r(line, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return;
    xypair[0] = strtod(token, &endptr);

    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return;
    xypair[1] = strtod(token, &endptr);
}

int main()
{
    double xypair[2];
    char line[] = "123456789,9215487";

    lineToXY(line, xypair);
    printf("%f, %f\n", xypair[0], xypair[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

You can use a struct

```
struct XYPair
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct XYPair lineToXY(char *line)
{
    char *token;
    char *saveptr;
    char *endptr;
    struct XYPair xypair = {0.0, 0.0};

    token = strtok_r(line, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return xypair;
    xypair.x = strtod(token, &endptr);

    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return xypair;
    xypair.y = strtod(token, &endptr);

    return xypair;
}

int main()
{
    struct XYPair xypair;
    char line[] = "123456789,9215487";

    xypair = lineToXY(line);
    printf("%f, %f\n", xypair.x, xypair.y);

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can use dynamic memory allocation

```
double *lineToXY(char line[])
{
    char *token;
    char *saveptr;
    char *endptr;
    double *xypair;

    xypair = malloc(2 * sizeof(double));
    if (xypair == NULL)
        return NULL;
    xypair[0] = 0.0;
    xypair[1] = 0.0;

    token = strtok_r(line, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return xypair;
    xypair[0] = strtod(token, &endptr);

    token = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &saveptr);
    if (token == NULL)
        return xypair;
    xypair[1] = strtod(token, &endptr);

    return xypair;
}

int main()
{
    double *xypair;
    char line[] = "123456789,9215487";

    xypair = lineToXY(line);
    if (xypair == NULL)
        return -1;
    printf("%f, %f\n", xypair[0], xypair[1]);
    free(xypair); // you have to call free when you no longer need the data

    return 0;
}
```

One thing you need to know is that `strtok_r` needs a mutable string passed to it, so if you pass a string literal, you need to copy it using `strdup` or `malloc` and `strcpy` or any other way you can think of.

The `sizeof` operator in your code is giving the size of a pointer, which is not the length of the string,  you can do it as with your code, but you need to rethink the algorithm since it has some issues.

Among the three solutions proposed above, the `struct` is the one I think works best.

Comment: How can you 'get around' that problem? Iteratively call a function returning a single value on each element of the array instead?

Comment: What does `isValidChar` do? I see other errors in your code now.

Comment: Checks if the char is 0,1,2,...,9,-,e or E and returns 0 if not and 1 if so

Comment: there is a function for that [`isdigit()`](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?3+isdigit), although it will not work for `E` or `e` or the minus sign, did my suggested code work? did it do what you want?